# Where do these additional solution configurations come from?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, projects-and-solutions

While checking my configuration manager, I noticed three additional solution configurations I haven't seen before:

- DebugSnk
- ReleaseSnk
- CodeAnalysis

Does anybody have any idea where these come from?

Comment: Check the history of the .sln file in your source control system, and see what the commit comment was when those lines appeared. Most source control systems have a "blame" feature that will tell you which commit changed/added each line in a file.

Comment: @Joe White: Nice idea, unfortunately I only just placed the source code under version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may have come from existing projects that you added to the solution. I have also seen this happen when upgrading projects from previous versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when browsing through them, I notice they all just set individual project configurations to Release or Debug.

Comment: I checked some previous projects I once added to the project and removed later. I noticed DebugSnk and ReleaseSnk probably originated from the [C5 collection library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/). CodeAnalysis originated from [RunSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/runsharp.aspx). So, great answer! ;p Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I hate that it does that! I feel like my solution is being polluted :)